# Max value of field using Elasticsearch Python API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to get the max value of a field "UID" from Elasticsearch using its Python API. When I try it using the below code I get an error.

```
res = es.search(index="some_index", body={"query": {"size": 0,
"aggregations": {
"maxuid": {
  "max": {
    "field": "UID"
  }}}}})
print(res)
```

> elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception', u'no [query] registered for [aggregations]')

I have a `curl` command for the same request which works, but when I use `query` in the body for the Python API it raises the above error.

This is the `curl` request which works and gives me the expected results. How to use this in the Elasticsearch Python API is the problem I'm facing.

```
GET some_index/some_doc/_search{
"size": 0,
"aggregations": {
"maxuid": {
"max": {
"field": "UID"
}}}}
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
res = es.search(
      index="some_index", 
       body={
        "aggs": {
          "maxuid": {
            "max": { "field": "UID"}
          }
       }
    }
)
print(res)
```

You can't specify aggregations inside query clause, aggregations and query are two different clauses and that's the reason you're getting that exception.

A rough structure looks like this:

```
res = es.search(
       index="some_index", 
       body={
        "query": {},
        "size": 0,
        "aggs": {
          "maxuid": {
            "max": { "field": "UID"}
          }
        }
    }
)
```

I haven't run the request so you might have to tweak it a bit.

PS: I am not a python guy :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `body` parameter is deprecated, you should specify the parameters individually to avoid a warning and possible breaking in the future:

> DeprecationWarning: The 'body' parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instead use individual parameters

There is no need for a `query` parameter, use `aggs` directly:

```
res = es.search(
          index = "some_index", 
          size = 0,
          aggs = { "maxuid": { "max": { "field": "UID" } } }
        )

print(res)
```